# "Item not writable" when trying to set a leaf from a bash script

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, ietf-netmod-yang

This is a simplified version of the YANG model I'm working with:

```
module echo
{
    namespace "http://namespace.com/ns/echo/1.0";
    prefix echo;
    import tailf-common
    {
        prefix tailf;
    }
    import ietf-inet-types
    {
        prefix inet;
    }
    ...
    container echo
    {
        ...
        container client
        {
            ...
            leaf ip
            {
                type inet:ipv4-address;
                tailf:info "Destination IP of remote device";
                tailf:snmp-name echoClientDestIp;
                tailf:hidden debug;
            }
        }//container client
    }//container echo
}//module echo
```

And this is a simplified bash script I'm running to change CDB:

```
#!/bin/sh

MAAPI=$CONFD_TOOLS_PATH/maapi

file_check $MAAPI
#...

$MAAPI --clicmd "unhide debug"
$MAAPI --set "echo:echo/client/ip" "$1"
#...
$MAAPI --clicmd "commit"
#...
$MAAPI --clicmd "hide debug"

exit 0
```

The rest of the model and the script are quite similar to what is here. What I get when trying to execute the script through the CLI (via a clifspec file) is:

```
"Failed to set value: item is not writable - "
```

So I tried to literally make it writable (for which I had to make it operational and thus add a callpoint) so the leaf ended up looking like this:

```
leaf ip
{
    type inet:ipv4-address;
    tailf:info "Destination IP of remote device";
    tailf:snmp-name echoClientDestIp;
    tailf:hidden debug;
    config false;
    tailf:writable true;
    tailf:callpoint useless-but-needed-callpoint-2;
}
```

Which yielded the same error. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Clients (assuming your script is a client) cannot set operational nodes - the server implementation (callpoint in your case) sets those for clients to read only. I'm not familiar with this interface at all, but have you tried checking if you have some sort of access control mechanism in place by default? Perhaps server logs will provide you with more information on what happens.